# "No suitable conversion function from 'std::string' to 'const char *' exists"

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, for-loop, char

I'm trying to write a simple loop that takes a string and goes through each character of said string and stores it inside another string (the same string every time). I want to use this loop to perform simple tasks, such as displaying a word in reverse, or displaying each character in a separate line (which is where the example provided below comes from). My code goes something like this:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
   c++
   string word;
   string ch;
   cout << "Please enter a word." << endl;
   cin >> word;

   int wordlength;
   int i;

   wordlength = size(word);

   for (i = 0; i < wordlength; i++) {
       word.copy(ch, 1, i);
       cout << ch << endl;
   }
}
```

But whenever I use this code, I get the error in the title:

**"No suitable conversion function from 'std::string' to 'const char *' exists"**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please paste the errors into your question, as opposed to a picture of them.

Comment: You are doing several things that are wrong: 1) all questions on stackoverflow.com must include all relevant information ***in the question itself as plain text***, suspicious links to dodgy external web sites can stop working at any time rendering the question meaningless; 2) All questions of the form "the following code doesn't work for some reason" must meet all requirements of a [mre], as explained in the [help], and the shown code does not. See [ask] for more information.

Comment: Accoring to the [std::string::copy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/copy/)
`size_t copy (char* s, size_t len, size_t pos = 0) const;`:
`s`:Pointer to an array of characters. The array shall contain enough storage for the copied characters.
`ch` should be `char*` instead of `string`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simply use *string*

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string word;
char *c;
  cout << "Please enter a word." << endl;
  cin >> word;

  int wordlength,  i;

    wordlength = word.size();

    for (i = 0; i < wordlength; ++i) {

     ch = word[i];

     cout << ch << endl;

   }
```

works either way too `word[i] = ch;`

Comment: Plain and simple,thank you,you did however forget to declare "string ch" after removing it,just pointing that out for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Size of string:

```
wordlength = word.size();
```

string::copy should be:

```
char ch;
....
word.copy(&ch, 1, i);
```

Comment: "string::copy should be" in this case it should be `ch = word[i];`

Comment: FYI, in C++17 and later, `std::size()` can be passed any container that has a `size()` method, which includes `std::string`, thus `wordlength = size(word);` is a valid statement

Answer (score 0):

From the c++ reference

size_t copy (char* s, size_t len, size_t pos = 0) const;

Essentially copy requires a char pointer/array as its first arg but you put a string so it threw an error.